# For some odd reason we have an "english" tag... Should we request that it be blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Not sure why [english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) isn't blacklisted. It's only on about eight questions right now because it looks like it was recreated about a month ago but I don't think it's needed for anything.

Is there a valid use case for this tag? It seems like it is the equivalent of the "movies" tag on Movies & TV.

Should we ask the CMs to blacklist this tag to prevent it from being created in the future?

Comment: We should have [stack] and [exchange] tags for the heck of it.

Comment: Jokes aside, +1 since this tag needs blacklisting.

Comment: Fersher. Along with 'grammar' and 'meaning'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've ensured that the latest incarnation of this tag will get auto-trimmed once the roomba deletes both remaining questions in another few weeks … assuming no one else adds it to their question in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of that, @NathanTuggy  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I trust the opinion of this "Catija" person, but since snailcar has vetted the request... I've conceded and marked the tag as "intrinsic" to the site: it won't block inbound migrations, but won't be allowed on any posts.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, we should nuke it from orbit, the same way the [japanese](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) tag is blacklisted on Japanese.SE.  It just doesn't make any sense to have a tag that applies to every single question.